# Algorithm for distribution of radiation

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, nuclear-engineering

Unstable atomic nuclei will spontaneously decompose to form nuclei with a higher stability. What is the algorithm for deciding what sort of it is? (alpha, beta, gamma, etc. Also, given that alpha and beta emission are often accompanied by gamma emission, what is an algorithm for deciding about the distribution of the radiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gamma emission is emission of a photon upon a nucleus transitioning from an excited state to a lower or ground state **of the same nucleus**.  The number of neutrons and protons in the nucleus is exactly the same before and after the gamma photon is emitted.

Beta decay results from a nucleus having too few or too many neutrons relative to the number of protons to be stable.  If there are too many neutrons, a neutron becomes a proton, an electron and an anti electron-neutrino.  If there are too few neutrons, a proton may become a nuetron by positron emission or electron capture. Whether beta decay is favorable can be calculated based upon the energies of the parent and daughter nuclei, as well as the energies of other particles.

Alpha decay is only observed in heavy nuclei, with at least 52 protons.  Iron (26 protons, 30 neutrons) is the most stable nucleus.  The [semi-empirical mass formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula) may be used to determine if alpha decay is energetically favorably, but even if it is, the rate of decay may be extremely slow.  There is a potential energy barrier to the particle's escape from the nucleus.  See [this reference](http://www.astro.uwo.ca/~jlandstr/p467/lec8-alpha_reactions/) for further information.